# Kinect Html5 Stream to web in existing C# Application

Tags: c#, html, webserver, kinect

For our university project we need the kinect video Stream accessible from another Device in the network. Preferable as a HTML5 Webserver. The Microsoft.Samples Webserver works only with the kinect1 and we need it for kinect 2. Another interesting solution is the one from intrael but we need to implement it in our own application. 
Are there any solutions I didn't find or could anyone give us a working example or hint how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone stumbles across this we solved this now with using a simple TCP Listener which listens for a connection:

```
 TcpListener srv = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 51530);
        srv.Start(1);

        client = srv.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Then we changed the Kinectpicture into a Bitmap and on every new picture we send the bitmap to the connected device:

```
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

            MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bitmap);
                bmp.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }


           // bitmap.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            Console.WriteLine("Bild wird über Socket geschickt");
            //reset the memory stream to start of stream
            imageStream.Position = 0;
            //copy memory stream to network stream
            imageStream.CopyTo(ns);
            //make sure copy is completed
            imageStream.Flush();
            imageStream.Close();

            //Makes sure everything is sent before closing it
            ns.Flush();
```

on the other side there is an android device which gets the network stream and translates it into a bitmap and shows it in an imageview.

Feel free to ask additional questions for needed clarification.